# How to add default slide for jQuery cycle that doesn't display in slideshow navigation?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jquery-cycle

I wanted to create a default slide that will display before the slideshow starts to cycle. The slideshow is to have a default/welcome slide that appears for perhaps 8-10 seconds and then it disappears and the slideshow cycles through the rest. The slideshow has a navigation that you can access the slides, EXCEPT for the default slide. You can't see the default slide unless you refresh your  browser.

I'm currently using jQuery cycle and I'm not sure how to achieve what I want to do. How do I set it to delay the slideshow and show this default slide while it doesn't activate in the navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Not a default option in most sliders, but it should still be relatively easy to accomplish. You put your 'default' slide in the same location on the page, in its own container (a div, probably). Then on click, you destroy that default element and start the cycle plugin up.

Comment: The slideshow needs to be run automatically and not on click. This would be one solution if it didn't have to do that. Initially I want it to load with the default slide and then it should disappear and the main slideshow begins. Is there a way this can be achieved with the before or delay parameter in jQuery cycle?